# Org-ref associate entry with local file

Tags: org-mode, bibtex, org-ref

I am a mendeley user trying to sync `org-ref` with my local biliography (bibtex format).

I'm having some trouble to run the function `org-ref-open-pdf-at-point`.
 Running this function while the cursor is on some citation emacs returns the 
 message "no pdf found for CITATION".

Let me try to explain my previous attempts:

First, each of my bibtex entries is fomatted as the following example (this is done automatically by mendeley)

```
@misc{Rockafeller1970,
author = {Rockafeller, Ralph Tyrell},
doi = {10.1515/9781400873173},
file = {:home/ariel/coisas/matematicasdavida/Livros/Rockafeller - 1970 - Convex Analysis.pdf:pdf},
isbn = {0-691-08069-0},
pages = {468},
title = {{Convex Analysis}},
year = {1970}
}
```

My first attempt was to set the variable `bibtex-completion-pdf-field` to `file`, but with no success. I also looked up the [Documentation](https://github.com/jkitchin/org-ref/blob/master/org-ref.org) and noticed that there is guidance for this sort of problem, but I also couldn't make their suggestions work.

Can someone help with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation of `org-ref-get-pdf-filename-function`. You can set it to either `org-ref-get-mendeley-filename` or `org-ref-get-pdf-filename-helm-bibtex`. Both the variants support Mendeley file fields.

Comment: Thank you so much! your suggestion solved my problem!! Unfortunately I still don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer but thanks again!